# Как удвоить значения поля таблицы, для которых выполняются условия в других таблицах. Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle12c

я застрял с одним учебным примером по sql (Oracle). Суть: у меня есть 3 таблицы: продажи, отделы и продукты. Код создания:

```
CREATE TABLE dep
(
   id     NUMBER (10) NOT NULL,
   city   VARCHAR2 (100) NOT NULL,
   name   VARCHAR2 (100) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT dep_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

-- продукты

CREATE TABLE prod
(
   id      NUMBER (10) NOT NULL,
   price   NUMBER (10) NOT NULL,
   name    VARCHAR2 (100) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT prod_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

-- продажи

CREATE TABLE sales
(
   time      DATE NOT NULL,
   dep_id    NUMBER (10) NOT NULL,
   prod_id   NUMBER (10) NOT NULL,
   cost      NUMBER (10, 2) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT sales_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (dep_id) REFERENCES dep (id),
   CONSTRAINT sales_fk2 FOREIGN KEY (prod_id) REFERENCES prod (id)
);
```

Код заполнения БД:

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1 .. 100 LOOP
      INSERT INTO dep
           VALUES (i,
                   CASE
                      WHEN i <= 50 THEN 'town1'
                      ELSE 'town2'
                   END,
                      'dep'
                   || to_char (i));

      INSERT INTO prod
           VALUES (i,
                   i * 10,
                      'prod'
                   || to_char (i));
   END LOOP;

   FOR i IN 1 .. 1000 LOOP
      INSERT INTO sales
           VALUES (trunc (to_date ('01.01.2016', 'dd.mm.yyyy')) + sys.DBMS_RANDOM.value (0, 0.99) - i,
                   mod (i, 100) + 1,
                   mod (i, 100) + 1,
                   i);
   END LOOP;

   COMMIT;
END;
```

Помимо прочих, для этой бд предлагалось реализовать запрос: увеличить цену в два раза у всех товаров, которые продавались в прошлом году в отделе 'dep10'.

Вот что у меня получилось:

```
UPDATE prod
SET prod.price = prod.price*2
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
FROM prod
                JOIN sales ON prod.id = sales.prod_id
                JOIN dep ON sales.dep_id = dep.id
                WHERE (DATEPART(Year, sales.time) = DATEPART(Year,DATEADD(Month, -1, GETDATE()))) AND dep.name = 'dep10' )
```

Как вы уже поняли - он нерабочий. Подскажите пожалуйста варианты реализации запросов такого типа? Для выборки записей прошлого года существует универсальный подзапрос? Пока продолжаю поиски в интернете, если найду - добавлю сюда.

Comment: `UPDATE prod
SET prod.price = prod.price*2
WHERE prod.id in (SELECT prod.id...` попробуйте так изменить update

Comment: Спустя пару часов разобрался с этим. Прикрепляю свой код, вдруг понадобится кому-то, вроде даже работает.               UPDATE prod
SET price = price * 2
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM sales 
  WHERE sales.prod_id = prod.id
  AND EXTRACT(Year FROM sales.time) = EXTRACT(Year FROM SYSDATE) - 1
  AND sales.dep_id = (SELECT id FROM dep WHERE name = 'dep10')
);

Comment: Вы просто забыли условие sales.prod_id = prod.id в корреляционном подзапросе. Подобных вопросов можно избежать, а для себя сэкономить время, написанием  [минимального и воспроизводимого запроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) до публикации вопроса.